# What objects do the cusps of Modular curve classify?

Tags: nt.number-theory

We know that a modular curve has a moduli interpretation, i.e, it classify elliptic curves with additional structure. But after we add cusps on it, is the cusps also has a moduli interpretation? What objects do the cusps classify?

Comment: I'm no expert - but I'm not sure that this question is of the 'research level' for which MO is intended.  It might be more appropriate on math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: They correspond to so-called "generalised elliptic curves"; I think the standard reference is Deligne-Rapoport. 

Comment: I think this is a perfectly good question for MO.  As Barinder writes, the cusps classify generalized elliptic curves with level structure.   This is worked out in Deligne--Rapoport (and I don't know of any other reference, although a more recent one may exist).

Comment: I agree with Emerton: this question is certainly of research level. The problem is that I think it is easy to give a three word answer --"generalized elliptic curves" -- but to do much better, I think one has to point to rather long, intricate papers, as I have in my answer below.

Answer (score 28):

If you just want a classical picture over the complex numbers, the objects lying over the cusp points are Néron polygons equipped with some extra structure.  To make a Néron $n$-gon, you take $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{P}^1$ ($n$-copies of the 2-sphere), and glue the components into a circular chain, with 0 in one sphere glued transversely to $\infty$ in the next.  The free action of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is part of the structure of the $n$-gon.

The nature of the extra structure depends on the moduli problem describing the modular curve.  Here are some examples:

- A Néron 1-gon is a nodal cubic curve, so the object lying over the cusp of $X(1)$ is a nodal projective line equipped with a point in the smooth locus.  Silverman gives a description of an analytic neighborhood of the cusp in his Advanced Topics book, in the section on the Tate curve.  There is a more formal description in chapter 8 of Katz-Mazur.
- For $X_0(N)$, the smooth locus parametrizes elliptic curves equipped with a cyclic subgroup of order $N$, and for each $m|N$ one has cusps that parametrize $m$-gons equipped with a distinguished point (the identity element) and a cyclic subgroup of order $N$ in the smooth locus.
- For $X_1(N)$, the smooth locus parametrizes elliptic curves equipped with a point of order $N$, and for each $m|N$ one has cusps that parametrize $m$-gons equipped with a distinguished point (the identity element) and point of order $N$ in the smooth locus.
- For $X(N)$, the smooth locus parametrizes elliptic curves equipped with an isomorphism from $(\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z})^2$ to the $N$-torsion, and for each $m|N$ one has cusps that parametrize $mN$-gons equipped with an isomorphism from $(\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z})^2$ to the $N$-torsion.

For each of these moduli problems, there are explicit formulas for the precise number of cusps for each $m$.  For $X_0(N)$, you can find it in Shimura, section 1.6.  For the others I think it isn't too hard to derive.

As others mentioned, Deligne-Rapoport's compactified moduli problems are described using the notion of generalized elliptic curve, which is a flat proper family of connected curves of arithmetic genus 1 and at most nodal singularities, equipped with a distinguished section and a "group law".  Unlike the smooth case, the group law is a necessary extra datum here because we wouldn't have a uniquely defined $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$-action on the $n$-gon over a cusp without it.

Answer (score 18):

Yes, the moduli problem extends to the cusps by way of **generalized elliptic curves**, i.e., certain semistable curves of arithmetic genus one.  For instance, with no level structure there is one point added in compactifying the $j$-line and this corresponds to a nodal cubic curve.

The basic ideas are pretty easy; the technical details less so.  For a thorough modern treatment, I recommend [this paper of Brian Conrad](http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/papers/kmpaper.pdf).

Comment: This is helpful for me. Thank you so much.

Comment: You're welcome.  Certainly I've gotten more than enough upvotes for this brief pointer.  